# What does 'length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent' mean?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame, which I can plot using matplot:

```
> dim(lhbyzone)
[1] 38070    21
> matplot(lhbyzone)
(no error occurs here)
```

But if I take the head of lh, and try, it gives me a strange error:

```
> foo <- head(lhbyzone,1000)
> matplot(foo)
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

So, maybe something to do with the names?

```
> dimnames(foo)
[[1]]
   [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "6"    "7"    "8"    "9"    "10"  
  [11] "11"   "12"   "13"   "14"   "15"   "16"   "17"   "18"   "19"   "20"  
  [21] "21"   "22"   "23"   "24"   "25"   "26"   "27"   "28"   "29"   "30"  
  [31] "31"   "32"   "33"   "34"   "35"   "36"   "37"   "38"   "39"   "40"  
...
 [951] "951"  "952"  "953"  "954"  "955"  "956"  "957"  "958"  "959"  "960" 
 [961] "961"  "962"  "963"  "964"  "965"  "966"  "967"  "968"  "969"  "970" 
 [971] "971"  "972"  "973"  "974"  "975"  "976"  "977"  "978"  "979"  "980" 
 [981] "981"  "982"  "983"  "984"  "985"  "986"  "987"  "988"  "989"  "990" 
 [991] "991"  "992"  "993"  "994"  "995"  "996"  "997"  "998"  "999"  "1000"

[[2]]
 [1] "time" "z1"   "z2"   "z3"   "z4"   "z5"   "z6"   "z7"   "z8"   "z9"  
[11] "z10"  "z11"  "z12"  "z13"  "z14"  "z15"  "z16"  "z17"  "z18"  "z19" 
[21] "z20" 

> dim(foo)
[1] 1000   21

> names(foo)
 [1] "time" "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "6"    "7"    "8"    "9"   
[11] "10"   "11"   "12"   "13"   "14"   "15"   "16"   "17"   "18"   "19"  
[21] "20"
```

The dimensions look the same?  It's odd, since matplot on the original frame works, but not on the head of the frame.  What could be happening here?

Edit, ok, so to answer some questions, and let's use thbyzone instead of lhbyzone, because it's smaller, and let's use head instead of head(..,1000) to make the data smaller

```
> head(thbyzone)
  time  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
1    1 46 38 44 45 42 44 45 43 41 42 36
2    2 46 36 42 43 42 43 44 44 39 43 32
3    3 45 35 40 41 40 42 41 42 36 43 31
4    4 41 30 36 37 39 38 40 34 35 39 30
5    5 39 30 34 33 40 38 35 30 33 35 34
6    6 35 29 32 32 41 37 35 35 36 35 35

> dimnames(head(thbyzone))
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"

[[2]]
 [1] "time" "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "6"    "7"    "8"    "9"   
[11] "10"   "11" 

> matplot(head(thbyzone))
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

> matplot(as.matrix(head(thbyzone)))
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

> matplot(thbyzone[1:6,])
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

> class(thbyzone)
[1] "cast_df"    "data.frame"

> str(thbyzone)
List of 12
 $ time: num [1:39432] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ 1   : int [1:39432] 46 46 45 41 39 35 33 33 36 47 ...
 $ 2   : int [1:39432] 38 36 35 30 30 29 28 28 28 33 ...
 $ 3   : int [1:39432] 44 42 40 36 34 32 30 30 30 32 ...
 $ 4   : int [1:39432] 45 43 41 37 33 32 30 29 30 41 ...
 $ 5   : int [1:39432] 42 42 40 39 40 41 38 33 36 43 ...
 $ 6   : int [1:39432] 44 43 42 38 38 37 36 36 38 44 ...
 $ 7   : int [1:39432] 45 44 41 40 35 35 33 30 31 39 ...
 $ 8   : int [1:39432] 43 44 42 34 30 35 34 33 34 41 ...
 $ 9   : int [1:39432] 41 39 36 35 33 36 32 31 31 35 ...
 $ 10  : int [1:39432] 42 43 43 39 35 35 33 33 35 42 ...
 $ 11  : int [1:39432] 36 32 31 30 34 35 32 30 28 30 ...
 - attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:39432] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "idvars")= chr "time"
 - attr(*, "rdimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    39432 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ time: num [1:39432] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    11 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ station_id: int [1:11] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

> traceback()
.... lots of lines ...
   "39405", "39406", "39407", "39408", "39409", "39410", "39411", 
   "39412", "39413", "39414", "39415", "39416", "39417", "39418", 
   "39419", "39420", "39421", "39422", "39423", "39424", "39425", 
   "39426", "39427", "39428", "39429", "39430", "39431", "39432"
   ))
4: as.matrix.cast_df(y)
3: as.matrix(y)
2: ncol(y <- as.matrix(y))
1: matplot(thbyzone[1:6, ])
```

Some more attempts:

```
> foo <- head(thbyzone)
> foo$time <- NULL
> matplot(foo)
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
> head(foo)
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
1 46 38 44 45 42 44 45 43 41 42 36
2 46 36 42 43 42 43 44 44 39 43 32
3 45 35 40 41 40 42 41 42 36 43 31
4 41 30 36 37 39 38 40 34 35 39 30
5 39 30 34 33 40 38 35 30 33 35 34
6 35 29 32 32 41 37 35 35 36 35 35
```

Edit:

```
> options(error=recover)
> matplot(thbyzone[1:6,])
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: matplot(thbyzone[1:6, ])
2: ncol(y <- as.matrix(y))
3: as.matrix(y)
4: as.matrix.cast_df(y)
5: `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
```

Comment: Well, without `lhbyzone` I cannot reproduce the error, but have you checked if it is caused by the names, e.g. by doing `names(lhbyzone) <- make.names(names(lhbyzone))` and `row.names(lhbyzone) <- NULL`?

Comment: Something's not right here. dim(foo) shouldn't show 1000 lines if it really is head(lhybyzone). `head` by default returns 6 rows. This is not the foo we're looking for. We like consistency here, otherwise we think "hey hey, you ain't doing what you think you're doing".

Comment: You're right, I was using `head(.., 1000)`. edited to update this

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.  When you get an error, it is helpful to look at the output of `traceback()` (and include it in your question).

Comment: `options(error = recover)` could also help you...

Comment: We need to know more about your lhbyzone object. Is it a matrix or a data frame? What if you take the first 1000 rows by going [1:1000,] instead of using head? What is class(lhbyzone)? What is str(lhbyzone)? Etc.

Comment: @Spacedman, it must not be a matrix (because `names(foo)` is not `NULL`), but beyond that these are fine questions. @HughPerkins, what happens if you try `as.matrix(foo)` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I can reproduce this from scratch, with `reshape` (but not with `reshape2`).  Something is indeed getting mangled by `head()`.

```
d <- data.frame(time=rep(1:10,10),x=rep(1:10,each=10),y=1:100)
library(reshape2)
str(dcast(d,time~x))  ## regular data frame
detach("package:reshape2")
library(reshape)
str(z <- cast(d,time~x))
matplot(head(z))  ## error
```

The specific problem is an interaction between `utils::head.data.frame`, which drops pieces of the object without keeping a completely consistent internal structure, and `as.matrix.cast_df` (called by `matplot`), which assumes that structure is there.

Adding the following method seems to fix the problem.

```
head.cast_df <- function (x, n = 6L, ...)  {
    stopifnot(length(n) == 1L)
    n <- if (n < 0L) {
        max(nrow(x) + n, 0L)
    } else min(n, nrow(x))
    h <- x[seq_len(n), , drop = FALSE]
    ## fix cast_df-specific row names element
    attr(h,"rdimnames")[[1]] <- rdimnames(h)[[1]][seq_len(n),,drop=FALSE]
    h
}
```

It might be worth contacting the maintainer about this, although the `reshape` package is (I think) deprecated in favor of `reshape2` ...

An alternative workaround is to switch from `reshape::cast` to `reshape2::dcast` if possible ...

Comment: Cool.  Good work!  I'm not sure how to use melt in reshape2 though ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990398/why-does-reshape2-melt-return-value-na-for-me ).  I guess I can just unload reshape2 to use melt, then load it in order to use dcast?

Comment: Oooh, I can do `reshape::melt` to use melt from reshape, and use directly `dcast` to use dcast from reshape2.  Cool, I will mark this answer as accepted. Thank-you Ben!

Comment: Its not head, because `matplot(z[1:6,])` fails similarly... The matplot thickens...

Comment: `cast` is creating something of class `cast_df`, and I guess its subsetting methods have an issue somewhere...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error. Although this answer does not apply to the specific example of this question, it may help future users who travel to this page for help with the error.

The names of my columns contained numbers and symbols such as `17:901`. This was throwing the error. Using the `make.names` function turned my column names into 'syntactically valid names' eg. `names(df)<-make.names(names(df))`

This solved the problem.

Comment: This did not work for me. Probably I have a different source of the error. Posted my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139742/column-names-listed-but-names-shows-null-error-in-dimnamesx-dn-length

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, but in my case one column (the last) had only NA values after agglomeration. Dropping this column restored sanity. You may check to confirm that you don't have a similar issue going on.

Comment: I have a different source of the same error, because no NA columns. Seems many bugs in R generate this error message.

Answer (score 2):

For those who received this error when using `mvoutlier::plot.mvoutlierCoDa(...)`, this error is produced when the argument `onlyout` (only plot outliers) is set to `TRUE` (default) and your dataset does not contain any outliers. Setting `onlyout=FALSE` should work. Run `mvoutlier.CoDa(df)$outliers` to see if your dataset contains outliers.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using a data.frame that I tried to convert to a data.table and gave me the same problem. I solved by:

```
data <- data %>% as.matrix(.) %>% as.data.table(.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly helpful FYI

I had a similar issue with xts objects with names that are ticker symbols.
objects y and z

> > names(z)

[1] "000100 KS" "000333 C2" "000423 CH" "000651 CH" "000660 KS" "002008 C2" "002415 C2" "002456 C2"  [9] "002475 CH"

> "002747 CH"
>
> > all.equal(names(y),names(z)) TRUE
> >
> > all.equal(index(y),index(z)) TRUE
> >
> > dim(y) 489 10
> >
> > dim(z) 489 10
> >
> > dim(y["2019-08",])

[1] 31 10

> > dim(z["2019-08",])

Error in `[.xts`(z, "2019-08", ) :

length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

but

> > names(z) <- make.names(names(z))
> >
> > dim(z["2019-08",])

[1] 31 10

No idea why xts[] selection works on object y but not z.

Now I just have to write a quick helper function to get the tickers back from the new "syntactically valid" (but no longer semantically valid...) names.

Comment: what is the output of class() and str() for the two objects? is the class identical?

Answer (score 0):

I received the error because I was using custom column names but had accidentally forgotten one column. It could be worth trying to run it without choosing the column names to make sure you aren't missing any.