# Why does reshape2 melt return value = NA for me?

Tags: r, reshape2

Why does reshape2 `melt` return `value` = `NA` for me?

It works for me with reshape, but not with reshape2:

Here is an example datafile:

```
"","station_id","year","month","day","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","h7","h8","h9","h10","h11","h12","h13","h14","h15","h16","h17","h18","h19","h20","h21","h22","h23","h24"
"1",1,2004,1,1,46,46,45,41,39,35,33,33,36,47,53,54,55,55,55,55,52,46,40,40,39,38,40,41
"2",1,2004,1,2,43,44,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,47,47,49,52,56,54,56,57,53,50,47,46,45,45,45
"3",1,2004,1,3,45,46,46,44,43,46,46,47,51,55,56,59,65,68,69,68,68,65,64,63,62,63,63,62
"4",1,2004,1,4,63,62,62,62,60,60,60,62,60,64,64,66,71,70,71,72,71,68,67,67,65,64,65,64
"5",1,2004,1,5,64,63,65,64,64,64,64,64,65,66,66,67,68,68,66,66,66,66,63,54,52,49,47,47
"6",1,2004,1,6,47,46,45,43,41,41,39,39,40,43,45,44,45,46,46,46,45,39,39,39,38,36,32,32
```

Let's say it is saved as `/tmp/foo.csv`, then:

Using reshape:

```
$ R
...
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library("reshape")
Loading required package: plyr

Attaching package: ‘reshape’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:plyr’:

    rename, round_any

> hlist <- NULL; for(z in 1:24) { hlist <- cbind(hlist, sprintf("h%d",z)) }
> 
> thh <- read.csv('/tmp/foo.csv')
> thm <- melt(thh,measure.vars=hlist,variable="hour")
> head(thm)
  station_id year month day hour value
1          1 2004     1   1   h1    46
2          1 2004     1   2   h1    43
3          1 2004     1   3   h1    45
4          1 2004     1   4   h1    63
5          1 2004     1   5   h1    64
6          1 2004     1   6   h1    47
> q()
```

Using reshape2:

```
$ R
...
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library("reshape2")
> hlist <- NULL; for(z in 1:24) { hlist <- cbind(hlist, sprintf("h%d",z)) }
> 
> thh <- read.csv('/tmp/foo.csv')
> thm <- melt(thh,measure.vars=hlist,variable="hour")
> head(thm)
  station_id year month day hour value
1          1 2004     1   1   h1    NA
2          1 2004     1   2   h1    NA
3          1 2004     1   3   h1    NA
4          1 2004     1   4   h1    NA
5          1 2004     1   5   h1    NA
6          1 2004     1   6   h1    NA
> q()
```

You can see that using `library("reshape")`, the `value` column has numbers, but for `libary("reshape2")`, it has `NA`, for the same data.

Comment: Please try to illustrate your questions with (made-up) data given in a way that allows to just copy/paste it into an R session.

Comment: Following up to @Roland's comment, see my updated answer for an example of what he means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are better ways to do what you are trying to do.

All of the following would work with `melt()` from `reshape2`:

```
# Not using hlist
melt(th, measure.vars=5:ncol(th), variable="hour")
melt(th, id.vars=1:4, variable="hour")

# Using your hlist
hlist <- NULL; for(z in 1:24) { hlist <- cbind(hlist, sprintf("h%d",z)) }
melt(th, measure.vars=as.vector(hlist), variable="hour")

# Using an alternative hlist
hlist <- paste0("h", 1:24)
melt(th, measure.vars=hlist, variable="hour")
```

It seems like `melt()` from "reshape" accepts a matrix as an input for `measure.vars`, but `melt()` from "reshape2" does not (which I find more reasonable).

#### Update: Example reproducible problem

FYI, below is a start-to-finish way that you can share this problem in a way that is convenient for other Stack Overflow users to copy and paste:

```
# Use set.seed when you want to use random numbers 
#   but want others to have the same data as you.
set.seed(1) 

# Make up some data that mimics your actual dataset
# Does not have to be your exact dataset
th <- cbind(
  data.frame(station = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3),
             year = 2004, month = rep(1:3, times = 3)), 
  setNames(data.frame(
    matrix(sample(100, 45, replace = TRUE), nrow = 9)),
           paste0("h", 1:5)))

hlist <- NULL; for(z in 1:5) { hlist <- cbind(hlist, sprintf("h%d",z)) }
# Cleanup any unnecessary stuff that your code leaves behind in the workspace
rm(z)
```

Now, demonstrate your problem. You can use `detach(package:package_name)` instead of having to quit and restart R.

```
library(reshape)
head(melt(th, measure.vars = hlist, variable = "hour"))
#   station year month hour value
# 1       A 2004     1   h1    27
# 2       A 2004     2   h1    38
# 3       A 2004     3   h1    58
# 4       B 2004     1   h1    91
# 5       B 2004     2   h1    21
# 6       B 2004     3   h1    90
detach(package:reshape)

library(reshape2)
head(melt(th, measure.vars = hlist, variable = "hour"))
#   station year month hour value
# 1       A 2004     1   h1  <NA>
# 2       A 2004     2   h1  <NA>
# 3       A 2004     3   h1  <NA>
# 4       B 2004     1   h1  <NA>
# 5       B 2004     2   h1  <NA>
# 6       B 2004     3   h1  <NA>
detach(package:reshape2)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, I worked my way through the method you give for generating data.  That's very helpful.  Thanks!  I'd give you extra points, but I'm only allowed to give one point per answer!

Comment: I've met same issue, after add `measure.vars = c(...)`, it works right now.