# Column names listed but names() shows NULL, Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r

When trying to fit `dynlm`, I get the error `Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`. There seem to be the same number of column names as columns according to some checks like `x0[0,]`, but no column names according to others, like `length(x0[0,])`. How to assign column names if these seem to exist, or otherwise fix the Error in dimnames?

MWE code below, data on [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f8JpBfHH_pfFhy3sUhoWA1qY2Lb21BEW_hbS8drmJ4k/edit?usp=sharing):

```
#setwd("~/Documents/dir1/dir2/dir3")
library(readODS)
data <- data.frame(read_ods("MWEdata.ods",col_names = TRUE, row_names = FALSE))
for (col in colnames(data)){
  data[,col] <- as.numeric(data[,col])
}
data <- data[!is.na(rowSums(data)), ]  # truncate to nonempty rows
data <- data[, colSums(data) > 5] # use only columns with >5 obs
y1 <- log(data[,"y1"]/(1-data[,"y1"])) # log likelihood ratio from probability
y2 <- log(data[,"y2"]/(1-data[,"y2"]))
xminusdummies <- data[ , ! names(data) %in% c("y1","y2","colname1","colname2","colname3","colname4", "colname41", "colname42")]
library(dynlm)
timedummies <- ts(data[ , names(data) %in% c("colname2","colname3","colname4", "colname41")])
y1 <- ts(y1)
y2 <- ts(y2)
colname43 <- ts(data[,"colname43"])
x0 <- ts(xminusdummies) 
fit <- dynlm(y1 ~ #L(y1,1)+ 
               L(x0,0:4)+timedummies) # Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
names(x0) # NULL, but
head(x0) # lists column names 
dim(x0) # 35 columns: colname7 to colname40 and colname43
x0[0,] # lists all 35 column names, but
length(x0[0,]) # 0
# names(x0) <- names(xminusdummies) # >1000 NA-s in names(x0)
x0[is.na(rowSums(x0)), ] # only column headings, no numeric rows, so seems should be fine. 
timedummies[is.na(rowSums(timedummies)), ] # only column headings, fine
```

The workaround of trying to remove the column names and just use the numeric part of the dataset did not work:

```
library(readODS)
datain <- data.frame(read_ods("MWEdata.ods",col_names = TRUE, row_names = FALSE))
columnnames <- datain[0,] # [1] colname1 <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
data <- datain[1:length(datain[,1]),] # Still has colnames. 
head(data)
```

still displays the column names.

Comment: dimnames(timedummies) is 2 in your case, that's why the error pops up

Comment: So not the column names but dimension names? I have not heard of these, thanks for pointing these out! How do I assign these or otherwise correct the problem?

Comment: `provideDimnames(timedummies)` did not change anything. `dimnames(timedummies)` still returns [[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "colname2"  "colname3"  "colname4"  "colname41"