# data.table subset rows when there is a lubridate interval object column

Tags: r, data.table

I am getting an error message with a `data.table` that I do not understand. I have a main `data.table` that I have subset based on ID variable. Once I have this second `data.table` I am again want to subset it by a vector of row indexes. Unfortunately, I cannot share my data and have not been able to reproduce the error with another data set. Sorry I cannot provide more detail than this. Can anyone tell what is going on with this limited info?

```
> class(auth)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> x <- auth[ID == auth$ID[1]]
> x[, authInterval := interval(x$AUTH_DT, x$AUTH_END_DT)]
> 
> # Find sequential auth intervals that overlap
> overlap <- sapply(1:(nrow(x) - 1), function(y) {
+   int_overlaps(x$authInterval[y], x$authInterval[y + 1])
+ })
> 
> x[, overlap := c(NA, overlap)]
> 
> # which two rows have overlap
> whichOverlap <- lapply(which(x$overlap), function(y) {c(y - 1, y)})
> whichOverlap
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

> 
> x[unlist(whichOverlap)]
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In cbind(ID = c("XXXXXX1", "XXXXXX2"), COMP_CD = c("280", "280"),  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

`dim` and `dimnames` output

```
> dim(x)
[1] 3 6
> dimnames(x)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "ID"           "COMP_CD"      "AUTH_DT"      "AUTH_END_DT"  "authInterval" "overlap"
```

Based on the `traceback` it seems like the subsetting screws things up with `print.data.frame`

```
> traceback()
3: `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste0(format(rn, right = TRUE, 
       scientific = FALSE), ":"))
2: print.data.table(x)
1: (function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

```
List of 1
 $ :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ ID          : num [1:2] XXXX1 XXXX2
  ..$ COMP_CD     : chr [1:2] XXX XXX
  ..$ AUTH_DT     : POSIXct[1:2], format: xxx xxx
  ..$ AUTH_END_DT : POSIXct[1:2], format: xxx xxx
  ..$ authInterval:Formal class 'Interval' [package "lubridate"] with 3 slots
  .. .. ..@ .Data: num [1:2] 7776000 7776000
  .. .. ..@ start: POSIXct[1:3], format: "xxx" "xxx" "xxx"
  .. .. ..@ tzone: chr "UTC"
  ..$ overlap     : logi [1:2] NA TRUE
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: `whichOverlap` is a list -- notice the `[[1]]` that prints when you show it. (And `lapply` always returns `list`s.) You need to use vectors, not lists to index data frames / data.tables. You can try `unlist(whichOverlap)`, or switch from `sapply` to `lapply`. It will solve the error, at  least.

Comment: Look at the subset line where the error is, I did use `unlist`. Additionally, I'm intentionally using `lapply` because of what my end goal is which I will want a list output for.

Comment: [This answer sounds potentially relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49889291/903061) - are you using nonstandard column names (like numbers)?

Comment: And could you at least share `dim(x)` and `dimnames(x)`?

Comment: Added. The parent `data.table` has similar results as this if that is relevant.

Comment: Interesting...so the subsetting is happening correctly, but it is manipulating something that makes it not play well with `print.data.table`.

Comment: Look at ``str(x)``, does everything makes sense?

Comment: Oh...interesting. It is not playing nice with the `authInterval` which is a type `interval` from the `lubridate` package. I think it is an `S4`. Not really sure how to fix it though. I've added what I could from `str`, removed the data parts.

Comment: Thank you for working through this with me. After figuring out more details I was able to do better google searches and find the answer. About to post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out, as this [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4315) issue states, this is a bug in `data.table` and handling columns that are S4 objects. There is also a workaround given here by making each element of the S4 column a list. So in my case the following fixes the issue. Notice that since the S4 columns are now lists, I had to change from using `[` to `[[`.

```
x[, authInterval := interval(x$AUTH_DT, x$AUTH_END_DT)]
x[, authInterval := as.list(authInterval)]

# Find sequential auth intervals that overlap
overlap <- sapply(1:(nrow(x) - 1), function(y) {
  int_overlaps(x$authInterval[[y]], x$authInterval[[y + 1]])
})

x[, overlap := c(NA, overlap)]

# which two rows have overlap
whichOverlap <- lapply(which(x$overlap), function(y) {c(y - 1, y)})
whichOverlap

x[unlist(whichOverlap)]
```